# Cannot print the correct values of array in C - GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, c

I have the following code, which opens a raster file using C, then gets some attributes, and then declares in line :23 a variable called line, then I read the raster as array using GDALRasterIO.

```
#include "gdal/gdal.h"
#include "gdal/cpl_conv.h"
int main()
{

    GDALDatasetH raster;
    GDALAllRegister();
    raster = GDALOpen( "/home/roger/Documents/98_GDAL_C++_snippets/data/Isle_wight.tif", GA_ReadOnly);
    if(raster==NULL)
    {
    printf("Invalid Raster Dataset");
    }
    else
    {
    GDALRasterBandH raster_band;
    int XSize, YSize;

    raster_band = GDALGetRasterBand( raster, 1);
    GDALGetBlockSize( raster_band, &XSize, &YSize);
    //int *pafScan;
    int nXSize = GDALGetRasterBandXSize (raster_band);
    int nYSize = GDALGetRasterBandYSize (raster_band);
    int *line = CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * nXSize * 1);
    //pafScan = (int*) CPLMalloc(sizeof(int)*nXSize);
    GDALRasterIO(raster_band, GF_Read,0, 0, nXSize,1, line, nXSize, 1, GDT_Byte, 0, 0);
    // looping through the pixels of this line;
    for (int k = 0; k < nXSize; k++) {
        // this is where you'd do your processing on the pixel 
        printf("%d-", line[k]);
        }

        CPLFree(line);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

However when iterating and wanting to print the values found in the first row of the array, I get either 0, or very long values (I guess because I am printing trash found in memory at this locations.

According to the documentation of gdal, from the snippet I am trying to use, this line should:

*There are a few ways to read raster data, but the most common is via the GDALRasterBand::RasterIO()
method. This method will automatically take care of data type conversion, up/down sampling and windowing. The
following code will read the first scanline of data into a similarly sized buffer, converting it to floating point as part of
the operation*

Everytime I compile the small program I get the following:

```
open_array.c: In function ‘main’:
open_array.c:25:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘GDALRasterIO’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     GDALRasterIO(raster_band, GF_Read,0, 0, nXSize,1, line, nXSize, 1, GDT_Byte, 0, 0);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I think that is because I am not assigning the line 25: GDALRasterIO to any variable (array), and then access the values of this variable by subscripting it in the for loop.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Should I declare let's say an array of nXSize and then assign it to the GDALRasterIO?

I have a python implementation that makes what I want to accomplish in C:

````
import numpy as np
import gdal 

path = "data/Isle_wight.tif"

ds = gdal.Open(path)
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
print(myarray.shape[0])
#print(columns)
for j in range(myarray.shape[0]-1):
    for i in range(myarray.shape[1]-1):
        print( myarray[j][i])
```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUQwI.png
````